# Getting "Access restriction error" when using Swing utilities in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, compiler-errors

I'm using Mac for the first time and I'm assuming this is a OS specific error, because the same code worked well on Ubuntu.

I'm trying to compile [***this code***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/TrayIconDemoProject/src/misc/TrayIconDemo.java) and Eclipse is showing me a lot of errors like this one:

> Access restriction: The method invokeLater(Runnable) from the type
>   SwingUtilities is not accessible due to restriction on required
>   library
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar

This is the first time I facing something like this and I don't know how to continue.

I'm using Java 8.

Comment: What usually works for me if something like this happens is to remove the JRE System Library from the project and then re-add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly have no clue *why* this happens, and it's a pain when I can't remember how I fixed it last time. Some Eclipse quirk, I suppose.

I usually fix this by removing the JRE System Library from the build path and then adding it back.

Answer (score 1):

I guess is that Mac does not support System Trays. You should check if support exists using the method `java.awt.SystemTray.isSupported()`. Does this return true?

EDIT: I guess the problem is more at the Eclipse IDE level? Try reinstalling Java.